# Delphi - RichEdit Zoom with code

Tags: delphi, zooming, richedit

If you load some text in the richedit and click left mouse button + move the mouse wheel, the text will zoom in or out, without loosing the text size formatting.

Is there an easy way to implement this functionality (zoom in/out) with some lines of code?

Thank you

ray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send [EM_SETZOOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774296(v=vs.85).aspx) to the rich edit control to sets the zoom ratio

```
procedure SetZoom(const RichEdit: TCustomRichEdit; const Value: Integer);
const
  EM_SETZOOM = (WM_USER + 225);
begin
  SendMessage(RichEdit.Handle, EM_SETZOOM, Value, 100);
end;

procedure TForm26.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetZoom(RichEdit1, 200);
end;
```

Comment: `EM_ZOOM` is already defined, in `richedit.pas` (in the Source\RTL\Win folder). Also, it would be much better to define `procedure SetZoom(const hRichEdit: THandle; const Value: Integer);` to make it clear it's not a `RichEdit` (the parameter name is confusing). Your call to SetZoom would also be clearer as `SetZoom(RichEdit1.Handle, 200);`, which is the default name for a RichEdit dropped on a form. Upvoted - just some suggestions. Fee free to ignore them if you want. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I would suggest changing the first parameter to `T(Custom)RichEdit` instead of `THandle`. A lot of things use `THandle` but are not suitable to use `EM_SETZOOM` or even `SendMessage()`.

Comment: @Remy: Yep. Even better.

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi XE6 and later `TRichEdit` has a `Zoom` property.  Set this to the percentage of zoom that you want.